# Making button clickable UITableView Xcode

Tags: ios, xcode

I made a custom tableview cell with a nib file in my project with a button. How do I make it so that when the button is clicked, I can execute a simple task, like printing hi? I saw other posts that are similar, but don't completely understand them.

Thanks in Advance....

Comment: Have you tried anything? if yes, share your code?

Answer (score 0):

You should **add target** to your button like this :

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let identifier = "ShipmentDeliveryFactorTableViewCell"
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: identifier, for: indexPath) as! ShipmentDeliveryFactorTableViewCell

    let object = factorArray[indexPath.row]

    cell.detailButton1.addTarget(self, action: #selector(showDetail(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
    cell.detailButton1.tag = indexPath.row


    return cell
}

@objc func showDetail(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let selectedCell = factorArray[sender.tag]
    print("selectedCell.id")
}
```